Understanding many in Megaparsec
I am trying to understand the behavior of many in the Megaparsec library for Haskell. I would have thought that many returns an empty list when its input parser fails, but this does not seem to be the case.
In particular, I am puzzled by the following, minimal code:
import Text.Megaparsec (Parsec, many, parseTest)
import Text.Megaparsec.Char (string)
import Data.Void

test :: Parsec Void String [String] -> String -> IO ()
test = parseTest

main = do
    test (many (string "a" >> string "b")) "ac" -- error
    test (many (string "a" <> string "b")) "ac" -- error
    test (many (string "ab")) "ac" -- []

Its output is the following:
1:2:
  |
1 | ac
  |  ^
unexpected 'c'
expecting 'b'
1:2:
  |
1 | ac
  |  ^
unexpected 'c'
expecting 'b'
[]

I don't understand why the first two tests fail and the third one does not.

The parser first eats an "a", so that means it is now trying to parse the string "a" >> string "b" or string "a" <> string "b" and therefore thus gets stuck. You should add try to prevent that.

Isn't it also stuck when it tries to parse string "ab" on "ac"?

The difference is that string "a" consumes input on success, and there is no way to un-consume it unless you wrap it in try.

What seems very weird to me is that Parsec and Megaparsec behave differently regarding that. For instance, the "same" code using Parsec
main = (parseTest (many (string "a" >> string "b")) "ac") >> (parseTest (many (string "a" <> string "b")) "ac") >> (parseTest (many (string "ab")) "ac")
yields three errors.

where the code of the previous comment imports Parsec, many, and parseTest from Text.Parsec and string from Text.Parsec.Char.

In Parsec, string consumes matched prefix, you should use string'.

There's no difference in what the parsers string "a" >> string "b" and string "a" <> string "b" will parse, only in what they return when the parse is successful (which is "b" for the first versus "ab" for the second), so it's no surprise that the first two cases behave the same (i.e., both fail).
The reason they fail is that the parser many p runs the parser p until it fails.  If the failure of p does not consume input, then many p succeeds and returns the list of results from the successful runs of parser p prior to its failure.  If the failure of p consumes input, then many p fails with the same "reason" as the final failure of parser p.
When the parser string "a" >> string "b" runs on the input "ac", the string "a" parser successfully parses the "a", and then the string "b" parser fails to parse the "c", without consuming input.  This causes the overall parser string "a" >> string "b" to fail, having consumed input (the input consumed by string "a", even though the parse causing the failure string "b" didn't itself consume any input).
Put this together, and many (string "a" >> string "b") runs the parser string "a" >> string "b" until it fails, which happens on the very first application with the reason that the parser string "b" expected a "b" but got a "c".  Because this failure consumed input (the "a" consumed by string "a"), the whole parser many (string "a" >> string "b") fails with the same "reason".
The parser string "ab" is a little different, and its behavior differs between Parsec and versions of Megaparsec since 4.4.0 (see the documentation for tokens).
In Parsec, the parser string "ab" applied to the input "ac" consumes the "a" and then fails on the "c", so it fails after consuming input.  This is probably a bad idea, which is why Parsec introduced string' in version 3.1.16.0.  The parser string' "ab" does the more sensible thing: it either consumes all of "ab" or it fails without consuming anything.  In particular, when it's applied to the input "ac" and can't consume "ab", it fails without consuming input.
In Megaparsec, string initially behaved like Parsec's string, but when they fixed this design flaw, instead of introducing a new string' combinator, they just made an incompatible change to string, so string "ab" in Megaparsec like string' "ab" in Parsec, either consumes all of "ab" or fails without consuming anything.
(To add to the confusion, Megaparsec also has a string' combinator, but it's a case insensitivie version of string and so has nothing to do with Parsec's version of string'.)

Thanks a lot for your answer. The explanation about string and string' is particularly illuminating. I use Haskell mostly for tiny projects and don't really care about efficiency (to some extent, of course). I would like to have a Kleene star parser combinator that would never fail, which would not make the distinction between eerr and cerr. It seems to me that I could define kleene p = many (try p), but I wonder: is there already a similar operator in mega.parsec?

I have taken a look at the library ReadP, very small in comparison with Parsec, which does not make the distinction between empty errors and consumed errors. However, its many is not eager, and retains in parallel all the possible prefixes. They have a munch term which looks like what I want, but it does not take a ReadP a as input, only a Char -> Bool. Is there a way to get an eager Kleene star which would never fail?

Your definition of kleene seems fine, and I don't think there's any existing similar function.  For your ReadP question, it might be best to ask this as a new question.  I have a possible answer, but someone else might very well have a better one.
